# Number of different ways to flip 5 switches

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having difficulty on a problem similar to the one below:

I have switch $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$. Each switch can either be on or off. How many different ways can the switches be on or off? The switches must be in order.

The only thing I could think of is to use permutations. I got $20$ using $5P2$. Does this sound correct? To me it almost sounds like way too many ways to flip just a few switches.

Comment: In a problem like this, try to start with a smaller number of objects (in this case, switches). How many possible ways are there with 1 switch? With 2? Etc... It'll help you get some insight and propose a formula which you can then try to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each switch can be either on or off, so each switch has $2$ possible states.

Since each switch can be on or off independently of the other switches, and the state of the total system is completely determined by the state of each switch, the number of possible states of the total system is equal to the product of the number of states of each switch. The total number of possible states is therefore $2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 = 32$.

Alternatively, we can enumerate all possible states with strings of five binary digits: the $k$-th digit is $1$ if the $k$-th switch is ON, otherwise the digit is $0$.

So the possible states are enumerated with $00000, 00001, 00010, 00011, 00100, \ldots, 11111$. That makes $32$ states in total.

Answer (score 1):

You would not want use permutations as the order in which you turn on the switches does not matter here. You can think of this problem in the two following ways-

Method 1: 
You can choose to flip each switch independently. Each switch can have two states- on or off. As this does not affect other switches. Answer would be $2{\times}2{\times}2{\times}2{\times}2=32$

Method 2:
You can add up cases where $n$ number of switches are flipped. Cases where $n$ switches are flipped are ${5\choose n}$. Hence total number of cases ${5\choose 0}+{5\choose 1}+{5\choose 2}+{5\choose 3}+{5\choose 4}+{5\choose 5}=2^5=32$